# want to add video upload option for front end user

Tags: custom-field, uploads, profiles

I have one user profile form with some fields and this from can be filled by user after successful registration. But those fields are not enough for me.Here i want to add video upload option to an existing from show that user can add and edit there video from front end.

Any Hint...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any plugin that allows that. Anyway, there are other options to let users upload videos to your webpage.

I would make a new user Role. You can install User Role Editor plugin to do that. After creating a new Role, you can give the permissions you want. You can allow them to use some resources of the backend, while you keep the rest out of their reach. If you are using a plugin to manage your multimedia section, you should give the permissions to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It not works for me but may be this will helpful for someone.